# Async issues with Apollo graphql API call

Tags: reactjs, async-await, next.js

In `spacexContext.js`,I'm making an API call the Spacex graphql API using the apollo client, then wanting to set the response to context. I'm logging the result when I use this context in other files, however I'm getting a pending promise instead of the returned data:

> Promise {< pending>}

I'm using an `async/await` function to retrieve the data, and my understanding is that the data is resolved before being returned, so I'm confused about why this error is happening. Any suggestions?

***spacexContext.js***

```
import { useState,useEffect,createContext } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client"

export const LaunchContext = createContext()


const getStuff = async () => {

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query GetLaunches {
        launchesPast(limit: 10) {
          id
          mission_name
          launch_date_local
          launch_site {
            site_name_long
          }
          links {
            article_link
            video_link
            mission_patch
          }
          rocket {
            rocket_name
          }
        }
      }
    `
  });

  return data
}

const data =  getStuff()

const LaunchContextProvider = (props) => {

    return(
        <LaunchContext.Provider value = {data}>
            {props.children}
        </LaunchContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default LaunchContextProvider
```

***index.js*** where the context is being used:

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { LaunchContext } from '../spacexContext'
import Link from 'next/link'


export const Home = () => {
  
  const data= useContext(LaunchContext)
  console.log(data) //pending promise instead of data
  return (
    <div>
      this is landing page
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by enabling top level await in the `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.experiments = {
      topLevelAwait: true,
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

..then used await on the function call in `spacexContext.js` :

`const data = await getStuff()`

Answer (score 0):

Any async function returns promise instead of data . The returned value is then resolved by thenable promise sturcture.
eg.

```
async function fn(){
      return 5;
    }

function fn2(){
   return Promise.resolve(5)
   }



function fn3(){
  return new Promise(resolve=>resolve(5))  
  }
```

they all are equivalent or more like same